# How do I remove the opacity from an input field in Bootstrap 5.3?

Tags: css, bootstrap-5, transparency

I want to make an input field (for a search bar) not translucent. I am using bootstrap 5.3. How can I achieve this result?

```
 <div class="input-group d-sm-none d-md-block">
  <div class="form-outline">  
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="searchbar"  placeholder="Search..."/>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to, first off, make the opacity 1 and declared that as important. Like so:

```
#searchbar {
 opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```
 <div class="input-group d-sm-none d-md-block">
  <div class="form-outline">  
    <input type="search" class="form-control" id="searchbar"  placeholder="Search..."/>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously, that has not worked.

I then tried to set the background color.

```
#searchbar {
  background-color:#ffff;
}
```

That worked, but not in the way I expected. I had hoped giving the input a background color would remove the opacity, which it didn’t.

Is there a way to get rid of the transparency on the input?

Comment: use css3 rgba color for your background transparency which is not effect div child elements. `background: rgba(255,255,255);`

Comment: The problem is that it is still transparent when using the “light” color mode introduced in Bootstrap 5.3. I want it to not be transparent while keeping the form-control’s styling.

Comment: want to make the input background equal to your div background?

Comment: When you look at exactly who/what is setting the transparency what do you find? (Using your browser's devtools inspect facility).